# Unable to connect to SOAP Service over SSL in JBoss EAP 6.2

Tags: java, soap, https, jboss, cxf

**Summary**: I have an SAAJ Client that calls a remote Web Service over HTTPS. Both Client and Server authentication via certificates is required. I can successfully invoke the service when running a JUnit test in my IDE, but fail to connect when running in JBoss.

**Keystore/Truststore Configuration Details**: In both the IDE and JBoss, I'm setting the keystore and truststore via system properties: `javax.net.ssl.keyStore`, `javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword`, `javax.net.ssl.trustStore`, `javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword`

**Logging Configuration**: In JBoss, I've enabled SSL Debug logging via the system property: `javax.net.debug=SSL`. I've also enabled CXF logging via a logging.properties file.

**JBoss SSL Logging Output Summary**:

- SSL logging shows no WARN or ERROR logs
- SSL logging shows a session is established at the time of the call to the remote service

**JBoss CXF Logging Output Summary**:

- CXF logging shows that the POST is sent to the service via Conduit null.http-conduit
- CXF logging shows this conduit is "configured for plain http", has "No Trust Decider", and has "No Auth Supplier" (I'm not entirely sure what all of this means, but it sounds relevant)

**Stack Trace**: Here's the actual stack trace I'm getting

```
    Caused by: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: JBWS024004: SOAP message could not be sent
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.saaj.SOAPConnectionImpl.call(SOAPConnectionImpl.java:124)
    at my.client.soap.MySAAJClient.invoke(MySAAJClient.java:37) [my-client-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response '403: Forbidden' when communicating with https://remote.service.url.here/
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1542)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1502)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1309)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:627)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.saaj.SOAPConnectionImpl.call(SOAPConnectionImpl.java:120)
    ... 19 more
```

**Other Information**

- I don't have direct access to the logs of the remote web service, but I'm told that they "don't show anything"
- CXF comes into play because it is used by JBoss. I don't have any CXF dependencies included in my project and it's not in play when I run the code in my IDE.

**What I've Tried**: I've been focused on CXF because again, this all runs fine when executed in my IDE where CXF is not in play and the CXF log that says the conduit has been "configured for plain http" scares me. I've tried including a `jboss-cxf.xml`, `jbossws-cxf.xml`, or `cxf.xml` configuration file in my WAR that includes the keystore and truststore configuration. This has not worked and I can't even tell that CXF is seeing these files.

**My Questions (Updated)**

- Is there any way to get JBoss/CXF to see that this is a secure connection and use the keystore/truststore configured via system properties?
- Is there any way for me to direct JBoss (via jboss-deployment-structur.xml maybe?) to use a different SAAJ implementation for my deployment?
- Do you have any thoughts on other things I should be looking into?

---

**Update 1**

I believe I've confirmed that the JBoss-CXF integration is the issue. I was able to remove JBoss's SOAPConnectionImpl by modifying the file *{JBOSS_HOME}/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/ws/saaj-impl/main/module.xml*. I commented out the module dependency `<module name="org.jboss.ws.jaxws-client" services="import"/>`.

After making this change, my application was able to connect to the remote service with no issues.

Although this shows that the JBoss-CXF integration is this issue, I can't modify the deployment environment in this way. I need to identify another solution.

Comment: Hey, have you tried using SOAPUI to make sure you could access the service?

Comment: Yes. I can access the service from SOAPUI just fine. The problem only exists when running in JBoss.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I'm facing exactly the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for system properties (or at least knowing the configuration of the system) as they might override whatever you specify in your deployment.

What version of cxf is used on the deployment environment? Do you have any info on the configuration of cxf on your deployment environment? From the documentation (http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html), I can see you need to configure WSS4J interceptors for cxf 2.0.x or earlier, so you could check if this is okay on your deployment environment.

Comment: I have confirmed the system properties are expected. I believe this version of JBoss uses CXF 2.7.7. I've followed all variations of instructions I could find for providing a CXF configuration file - with no luck. I'm familiar with the CXF tlsClientParameters configuration, but, seem to be unable to get JBoss/CXF to pickup any configuration files I include in the WAR.